# Lubuntu 17.04 on Virtualbox 5.1.22

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu

I'm running 32bit Lubuntu 17.04 on Virtualbox 5.1.22. For some reason when I enter my password and login to my user name I get a black screen. When I close the guest window (power off the machine) and try to login as a Guest Session I can see the desktop. Is there some diagnostic tool I can use to determine what might be causing the black/blank screen when I try logging in with my user?

Comment: Do you get OpenBox menu when you right click on that black screen?

Comment: No, I don't get anything. No mouse clicks, no keyboard buttons, nothing.

Comment: I had some similar problem and I needed to reinstall VBoxLinuxAdditions. Try to mount the Guest additions cd and install it. Do you know how to do that?